# How to add property with hyphen to a Typescript object declared as any

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript object declared as any type.
Now I need to append a field after an instance of these objects. 
I know I could just do it with

`myObject.myProperty = 'true';`

but unfortunately the property I need to add contains a hyphen so this is not possible.

I've tried:

`myObject['my-property'] = 'true';`

and

`Object.defineProperty(body,'my-property','true');`

but both of them failed.
Is there any way of doing this on typescript (without serialising to raw string or json)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript as far as I can tell. `myObject['my-property'] = 'true';` should work. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20myObject%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20'bar'%2C%20'qqq-aaa'%3A%20123%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmyObject%5B'my-property'%5D%20%3D%20'true'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.writeln(JSON.stringify(myObject))%3B

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to map type using . `&` operator

```js
let fn = (anyItem: { myProperty: string } & { [key: string]: any }) => {
  anyItem.myProperty // string
  anyItem.otherProperty // any
}
```

`{ [key: string]: any }` means that any key on this type will return `any`, but merged with `{ myProperty: string }` will behave normally on `myProperty` key

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20fn%20%3D%20(anyItem%3A%20%7B%20myProperty%3A%20string%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20anyItem.myProperty%20%2F%2F%20string%0D%0A%20%20anyItem.otherProperty%20%2F%2F%20any%0D%0A%7D)